# Is it possible to access an outter class instance from an inner class instance?

Tags: java

Imagine I have a class with an inner static class

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
    }
}
```

Having an instance of class B somewhere else in the code, can i access the class A instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible, if you add an explicit reference to A, eg.:

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
        private final A a;

        public B(A a){
            this.a = a;
        }
    }
}
```

If the inner clas B wasn't static, then this reference would be implicitly available (with a different syntax):

```
public class A {
    public class B {
        ...
        A a = A.this;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. Since you declared B `static`, there is no reference to A.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `B` is a `static` class and all its instances are *not bound* to an instance of `A`.

If `B` weren't `static`, then it would be possible.